# How to change the default width of pnotify Jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, responsive-design, pnotify

I'm using this pnotify plugin to display tooltips notifications on my site. The default width of tooltip is 300px but thats not showing properly on iphone.
So how can I change it's width ?
If I inspect element , i see that the `width:300px` is an inline style property. I went into `jquery.pnotify.min.js` file and removed the `width:300px` property and added my own custom width in `pnotify.css` file for the `.ui-notify`. But still the width does not change.

Any ideas ?

Plugin link:

http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `!important` to your rule. This will override it for sure.

Example:

```
.ui-notify {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: Actually I have two different css files , one for my main site on PC and another for mobile as mobile.css .. I have set this !imp property in mobile css but it affects the main site too. What I want is to have its width 300px on main site but on mobile site it should be 245px; How can I do it?

Comment: In mobile CSS you should override it with `!important` inside `@media` section and more specific CSS selector, like `a.ui-notify` (or whatever `.ui-notify` tag is). It will work only for mobile this way. Can you provide excerpts from both CSS? (w/ `@media`). You can read about specifity of CSS rules here: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: Ok it worked, I was just adding a extra semicolon in syntax. Anyway thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

I realise this question is old and already has an accepted answer - but there's a better way to set the "default width" of the pnotify popups, without resorting to css with `!important` flag to override the actual default value. Javascript:

```
PNotify.prototype.options.width = "500px";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a class to your notice and do something like this:

```
 var notice = new PNotify({
  ...,
  addclass: 'custom-notif',
  ...,
});
```

And then with css:

```
.custom-notif {
    top: 5% !important;
    left: 5% !important;
    width: 90% !important;
}
```

This would allow you to create a bunch of different notifications (display at the top, display at the bottom, etc) where overriding `.ui-notify`'s style wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Now (dec 2014), according to the [sources](https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify/blob/master/pnotify.core.js), you have the `width` property for this:

```
var notice = new PNotify({
  ...,
  // Width of the notice.
  width: "300px",
  ...,
});
```

This would be best if you wish to set only the width.